# Imprimir dos listas de For en una sola linea, Python

Tags: python, bucle-for

Buen dia, Tengo un pequeño problema con mi codigo. Busco imprimir dos listas que me dan dos `for` en una sola linea.

Se que si imprimo la variable del `for` fuera del ciclo solo me dara el ultimo resultado de la lista, Por eso use el `+= variable + '\n'`, De esa forma la lista me imprime fuera del ciclo.

Lo mismo hice con el siguiente `for` pero para juntar cada resultado en una sola linea es mi problema.

Este es el primer `for`

```
ngc =""
for codigo in soup.find_all('a',class_='cover',style=True):
    a = (codigo.get('href').rsplit('/')[2])
    ngc += a + '\n'
```

Y me dará una lista suponiendo que es.

```
32323
23213
43243
```

El siguiente `for` me dara una lista de nombre

```
nmc=""
for name in soup.find_all('div',class_='caption'):
    b = (name.getText())
    nmc += b + '\n'
```

Suponiendo que son:

```
Shinge
Orashe
Menke
```

y busco que mi resultado sea:

```
32323 Shinge
23213 Orashe
43243 Menke
```

intente quitando el ultimo salto de linea con `end=""` no da ni un resultado, Tambien use el `rstrip('\n')` y tampoco me funciono, El resultado que me devuelve son las listas una debajo de otra, Osea al terminar la primera lista continua con la siguiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar una funcion que se llama zip, a esta funcion le puedes pasar 2 listas de la misma longitud y te junta los elementos en otra lista hecha de tuples, por ejemplo:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]

nuevaLista = zip(a, b)
//nuevaLista = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
```

Con eso puedes hacer un loop sobre las dos listas a la vez

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i, j in zip(a, b):
    print(i, j)
```

eso quedaria asi:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

en tu caso seria asi:

```
 codigos = soup.find_all('a',class_='cover',style=True)
 nombres = soup.find_all('div',class_='caption')
 for codigo, nombre in zip(codigos, nombres):
    a = (codigo.get('href').rsplit('/')[2])
    b = (name.getText())
    print(a, b)
```

Puedes trabajar individualmente con cada variable del loop y luego las imprimes

Espero te sirva mi respuesta

Comment: No sabia que se podía hacer scraping de esa forma, Muchas gracias me funcionó!